# Good or Bad Performance: uglify (minify) a .min file?

Tags: performance, gruntjs, gulp, minify, gulp-uglify

**Is there any benefit or downside to uglifying a .min file?**

Using `Gulp` for example, including `jquery.min.js` in your `uglify task` will make your output script *better or worse* in regards to performance?

Are we better off running `jquery.js` in the task instead?

Comment: I like to know the answer too, however I can't find any information on this. I guess the best practice is to avoid having minified files in development and to apply uglify on unminified file only, especially if you plan to concatenate these files together as well.